# White binary image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, binary

in Matlab,

if I do:

```
output = false(5, 5);
imshow(output);
```

it will show me a black square instead of a white binary square image. Is there any reason to this? How can I output a white binary square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `false` is mapped to `0`, and `true` is mapped to `1`.
Also, when showing images, higher number is shown by higher intensity. White has more intensity than black.

Another way to think about it, is that usually you have 256 values - `0-255`. `0` is totally black and `255` is totally white. Now, imagine that you do a quantization to two colors. It is now obvious that `0` should be black.

In order to show white square, use

```
  output = true(5,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use imcomplement

```
imshow(imcomplement(false(5, 5)))
```

or modify the default color mapping (quoting from imshow's documentation)

```
imshow(X,map)
```

displays the indexed image X with the colormap map. A color map matrix may have any number of rows, but it must have exactly 3 columns. Each row is interpreted as a color, with the first element specifying the intensity of red light, the second green, and the third blue. Color intensity can be specified on the interval 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the figure's [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) to customize how MATLAB maps values to colors:

```
BW = [false,true;true,false];
imshow(BW)
set(gcf, 'Colormap',[1,1,1;0,0,0])
```

[image: screenshot]